# Question about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

So I have studied the FOTC, but not really sure of what I read so this question is just to help me learn the FOTC and understand how to do problems like it.
$$ if $$
$$F(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{sin^3(t)}dt$$
$$ Find F'(0.42)$$

So my first thought is to say taht $F'(x) = f(x)$ and that $F'(x)$ is actually $\sqrt{sin^3(x)}$

Is this correct so far? How do i go on?

Comment: No, this is not correct. $F(x)$ is not $\sqrt{\sin^3(x)}$, and $F'(x)$ is not equal to $F(x)$. I'd suggest carefully rereading the statement of the FTC given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part).

Comment: Sorry corrected

Answer (score 3):

no your method isn't correct.

For instance, see this integral:

$$\large F(x) =\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(t)dt$$

To find $F(x)$, use this mnemonic device:

$$\text{Top*derivative(Top)} - \text{Bottom*derivative(Bottom)}$$

To put into math terms:

$$\large F'(x) = g(b(x))*b'(x) - g(a(x))*a'(x)$$

So in your integral it would be:

$$\large F'(x) = \sqrt{\sin^3 x}*1 - \sqrt{\sin^3 (0)}*0$$

$$\large F'(x) = \sqrt{\sin^3 x}$$

Comment: Wow thank you! This is really what I needed, now I can answer any FOTC question!

Comment: Small suggestion: maybe you want $t$ instead of $x$ as the variable of integration.

Comment: @Panthy no problem

Comment: @JasonKnapp oh thanks +1. Will fix